# Converting IP address string to an int

Tags: python

I am rather new to python and seeking help regarding a homework prompt of mine.

Here is the exact prompt from the professor:

> Both
>   start_ip and end_ip should be 12-digit integer numbers. That is to make the IP
>   lookup easier. First split the ip address at periods, then add leading zeros to each number
>   to make each of them three digits, i.e. the string 102.1.2.0 becomes the integer
>   102001002000. Hint: use the string zfill() method (zero fill) and do operations as
>   strings to build a string of digits and only convert to an int after the whole number has
>   been built (note that when converted to an int leading zeros of the first number will be
>   lost since an int does not have leading zeros – that is OK).

So basically we remove the dots from the ip string, reformat the string to be 12 characters long, and then convert that to an int.

For example: 
0.0.0.0 should go to -> 000.000.000.000
102.1.2.0 should go to -> 102001002000

This is what I came up with, but it doesnt seem to work:

```
def ip_to_int(ip):
ip = ip.split('.')
ip = ip[0].__str__() + ip[1].__str__() + ip[2].__str__() + ip[3].__str__()
ip = ip.zfill(12)
return int(ip)
```

For example, when I plug the ip 0.0.0.0 into this code, it returns the int 0.
And when I put in 1.0.0.0 , it results in 1,000. I am not able to pinpoint why this is happening.

Like I said I am new to python so some of what I did might not entirely make sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should state _why_ it doesn't work, i.e. what the result is

Comment: what do you think `ip.zfill(12)` is doing?

Comment: Also `ip[0]` is already a string, no need to call: `ip[0].__str__()` and etc

Comment: `note that when converted to an int leading zeros of the first number will be lost since an int does not have leading zeros – that is OK)` And so `0.0.0.0` should be `0`, correct?

Comment: According to his explanation, 0.0.0.0 should go to 000000000000. Because we want to fill in all 12 characters with 0s.

Comment: @andrewDev15 But that's not an integer, you understand that right?

Comment: Yes. Perhaps he forgot to clarify that. So I suppose the answer to your initial question was yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the professor is asking regarding the zfill is to do this:

```
ip =  ip[0].__str__().zfill(3) 
    + ip[1].__str__().zfill(3) 
    + ip[2].__str__().zfill(3) 
    + ip[3].__str__().zfill(3)
```

but notice that your list already contains strings so you don't need to convert those again, then your code would be:

```
ip =   ip[0].zfill(3) 
     + ip[1].zfill(3) 
     + ip[2].zfill(3) 
     + ip[3].zfill(3)
```

and to make it even more elegant and pythonic you could do:

```
ip = ''.join([i.zfill(3) for i in ip])
```

Comment: Why are you calling `.__str__()`?

Comment: @alfasin that was in the original code, I wouldn't do that either.

Comment: @JosepValls If you wouldn't do that, then change your answer to reflect it.

Comment: This fixed some of the issues. However, some IP addresses still aren't formatting to 12 characters.

Comment: @andrewDev15 such as?

Comment: the ip "0.0.0.0" will go to 0. According to his explanation, it should go to 000000000000

Comment: Alright well nonetheless another example is 1.0.0.0 goes to 1000000000 (only 10 chars)

Comment: @andrewDev15 Remember my comment from above: `note that when converted to an int leading zeros of the first number will be lost since an int does not have leading zeros – that is OK)` So that's valid.

Comment: Okay I understand all the explanations. Thanks very much. Appears to be working now. I just misunderstood what zfill was going to do in my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
def ip_to_int(ip):
    return int("".join([n.zfill(3) for n in ip.split('.')]))
```

---

*The explanation:*

First we split the `ip` string into parts:

```
     ip.split('.')
```

Then we create a list, filling every part to the string of the length `3`:

```
     [n.zfill(3) for n in ip.split('.')]
```

Next we join them (`"".join()`) and convert the resulting string to an integer (`int()`).

Answer (score 1):

The way you are currently solving the problem, you take your string `"102.1.2.0"`, then you split it into an array `["102", "1","2","0"]`, then put the string together `"102120"`, and then pad with zeros. `000000102120`. Do you see the answer now?

Try to solve it yourself first, then see if this is the answer you came up with.

> You need to `zfill(3)` each string before putting them together. You could type this out all the way, `str(ip[0]).zfill(3) + str(ip[1]).zfill(3) + ...` but it is better coding practice to use a `for` loop if your professor has gone over those already. Try `for i in range(4): result = result + str(ip).zfill(3)`

Answer (score 1):

It's late but:

```
def ip_to_int(ip):
    m = ''
    for i in ip.split('.'):
        m += (3-len(i))*'0' + i
    return int(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
int(''.join([i.zfill(3) for i in ip.split(".")]))
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47006847/4909087, your answer is a dupe of one of their options.